# How to convert a string array to a generic array type while allowing both non array and array as generic type parameter for the class?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, type-conversion, type-parameter

I have an `Option<T>` that works great for any type that be converted from string, and now I am trying to extend that to cover `Option<T[]>` (ie, `Option<int[]>)`. Afraid I may be coming at this problem with too many C++ templates under my belt. Having trouble wrapping my head around the seemingly inadequate C# generics. I can detect when T is an array, but then I can't make any use of `typeof(T).GetElementType()`.

I think I may be in one of those XY problem valleys, where I am just coming at this from the wrong direction and can't see the path over the rise.  Any ideas how to get unbocked?  I've tried everything I can think of and spend the past couple of days trying to figure out to get unblocked.
I would add that I can arrange to parse the comma delimited string into an array of strings prior to conversion. The code below is a simplified extract from some of what I've tried.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflowCS
{
    internal static class ConversionExtensionMethods
    {
        internal static T ChangeType<T>(this object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        internal static T ChangeType<T>(this object[] objects)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!typeof(T).IsArray) throw new Exception("T is not an array type.");

                var converted = new object[objects.Length];

                foreach (var item in objects)
                {
                    // AFAIK, converstion requires compile time knowledge of T.GetElementType(),
                    // but this won't compile.
                    converted.Add(item.ChangeType<typeof(T).GetElementType())>
                }

                return (T)converted; // And this won't compile either.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }


    internal class Option<T>
    {
        public T Value;

        public Option() {}

        // This works fine for non-arrays
        public bool SetValue(string valueString)
        {
            try
            {
                Value = valueString.ChangeType<T>();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        // I think I am in an XY problem valley here.
        public bool SetValue(string[] valueStrings)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!typeof(T).IsArray)
                {
                    throw new Exception("T is not an array type.");
                }

                // The crux of my problem is I can't seem to write pure generic code in C#
                var convertedElements = new List<!!!Cannot use typeof(T).GetElementType() here!!!>();

                foreach (var item in valueStrings)
                {
                    // The crux of my problem is I can't seem to write pure generic code in C#
                    convertedElements.Add(!!!Cannot use typeof(T).GetElementType() here!!!);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var opt = new Option<int>(); // Works fine.

            var integerList = new Option<int[]>();

            integerList.SetValue("this,that,whatever"); // This fails at run-time.

            foreach (var item in integerList.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

The parser (not shown) can detect arguments of the form
`Opt:1,2,3` or
`Opt:"short sentence",word,"string with quotes\" in it"`, etc.
I'd rather not have the parser try to figure out what type the Opt Option's array elements are. The `Option<T>.SetValue(string[] strings)` function should be able to handle that.
I haven't even tried test/implement `Options<List> yet, though I suspect that would be much easier.

Comment: the point of generics is that you do not need to switch based on the **actual** type. Instead the generic members works **for all** types (satisifying the generic constraint of course). So if your method does different things based on different types, you should have different methods in the first place. Furthermore generics are a **compile-time**-thing. You have to know the actual time at compile-time.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, well from the C++ perspective, I would agree with you, but that is not the case in C#.

Comment: I honestly have no clue about C++. That **is** how generics work in C# works.

Comment: C++ templates are not the same thing than C# generics. Generics comes from templates, strongly typed templates and fully OOP. Hence generics can do more and less than templates.

Comment: I suppose your type `T` actually **is** `List<int>` for example. There´s no need to do `new List<T>`, which would be a `List<List<int>>` then. However your class seems to assume `T` actually **is** some type of collection, so you need a generoc constraint.

Comment: Well all of that I already know.  How to solve my problem, that's why I am here.

Comment: Let me put it another way: `internal static T ChangeType<T>(this object obj)` will fail with something like "Can't convert T][] to T' or there-abouts.

Comment: FIrst, you cannot contrainst the generic type parameter to array yet, as I know and we can't do that in VS2017 C# 7.3 to be able to write: `internal class Option<T> where T : Array` or `class Option<T[]>`.

Comment: @OlivierRogier, anyway you can think of to get around this restriction?

Comment: It sure looks like an XY problem to me. First, I would advise against working with delimited strings altogether. Second, instead of attempting to convert the type of an object array, you can use linq to manipulate the values inside the array, and return an IEnumerable<T> (or use `.ToArray` if you really need an array at the end).

Comment: So, it's a program arguments handler.  Something like `IntArray:1,2,3` on the command line, so the parser calls `Option<int[]>.SetValue(string "1,2,3")` through an IOption<T> interface.

Comment: Third, what would you expect the result of the following code to be? `integerList.SetValue("1,2,NotANumber");` Should the array contains 1 and 2, or should it be null (or uninitialized)? Fourth, What if the string is delimited using `;` or ` ` (space) or `|` or whatever other char the user of your code thinks is a good delimiter?

Comment: `integerList.SetValue("this,that,whatever");` what should that do on an `int[]`-generic argument?

Comment: That ? `input.Split(delimiter).Select(c => (T)Convert.ChangeType(c, typeof(T)))` (this will easily explode depending of the input string)

Comment: And one more thing - `integerList.SetValue("this,that,whatever");` will call this overload: `SetValue(string valueString)` - you probably meant to use `SetValue(string[] valueString)` which means you have to do something like this: `integerList.SetValue(new [] {"this","that","whatever"});`

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I would expect it to throw an exception if one of the string in the list could not be converted.  That's irrelevant detail at this point.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes, exactly!  You can't write generic code that handles both arrays and non-arrays.  So the other attempt is to split the string and call `SetValue(string[] valueString)`, except, that either won't compile, or will fail with a null exception, depending on the implementation.  You've hit on the crux of the problem exactly. I do have lot of code that parses the command line and can easily call the correct function, depending on whether typeof(T).IsArray, but I can't implement a converted that works when T is an array.

Comment: It's not that you can't do it, it just that it's cumbersome and might not be a very good choice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to allow both non-array and array generic types parameters:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
```

**SetValue(string valueString)**

```
public bool SetValue(string valueString)
{
  try
  {
    if ( typeof(T).IsArray ) throw new Exception("T is an array type.");
    Value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(valueString, typeof(T));
  }
  catch ( Exception e )
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

**SetValue(string[] valueStrings)**

```
public bool SetValue(string[] valueStrings)
{
  try
  {
    if ( !typeof(T).IsArray ) throw new Exception("T is not an array type.");
    var thetype = typeof(T).GetElementType();
    var list = valueStrings.Select(s => Convert.ChangeType(s, thetype)).ToList();
    var array = Array.CreateInstance(thetype, list.Count);
    for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++ )
      array.SetValue(list[index], index);
    Value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(array, typeof(T));
  }
  catch ( Exception e )
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

**The test**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Non array
  var opt = new Option<int>();
  opt.SetValue("10");
  Console.WriteLine(opt.Value);
  Console.WriteLine();
  // Array
  var integerList = new Option<int[]>();
  integerList.SetValue(new[] { "1", "2", "3" });
  foreach ( var item in integerList.Value )
    Console.WriteLine(item);
  // End
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

```
10

1
2
3
```

Comment: Awesome! `var array = Array.CreateInstance(thetype, list.Count);` was the conceptual bit I was missing.  I can't believe I thrashed about for two days over this one.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not simply `Value = valueStrings.Select(s => Convert.ChangeType(s, thetype)).ToArray();`?

Comment: It does not work because it can't cast... I tried many things until found this solution.

Comment: Ah, yes, the `Convert.ChangeType` returns `object`, forgot about that part for a minute there....

Comment: I think the problem here, is that `typeof(T).GetElementType()` cannot be resolved at compile time. If it could, then a pure generic solution would have been available. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is solved at runtime: `ldtoken !T / call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle) / callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetElementType()` (ILSpy)